# XSLT: How to invoke xs:boolean() constructor with a parameter?

Tags: xml, xslt

I tried the expression below but received a parse error:

> ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'boolean'
>   is not a valid object reference.'

```
<xsl:variable name="elemVal">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="boolVal" as="xs:boolean" select="xs:boolean($elemVal)"/>
```

Comment: Seems likely that you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor, but your XSLT code is written in XSLT 2.0. You need to install and use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: As a workaround you can use `choose-when-otherwise` option to set variable as string `true` or `false`  manually :)

Comment: Can you confirm that **elemVal** actually contains a value, and that it is in scope when you calculate **boolVal**?